# Allow non customers (anyone) to add product tags

Tags: product, tags

Currently when anyone tries to add/write product tags onto a product, if they are not a customer it forces them to login or register.

Is there a way I can bypass this check and allow anyone to add product tags and ideally auto approve them so they don't go into the pending section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to rewrite the action `Mage_Tag_IndexController::saveAction` and remove the authentication constraint.

```
    if(!$customerSession->authenticate($this)) {
        return;
    }
```

And for auto approval  replace in the same method

```
->setStatus($tagModel->getPendingStatus())
```

with

```
->setStatus($tagModel->getApprovedStatus())
```